# How can I block a pthread to print a global variable from main and then continue the pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I have a main function that creates a pthread. I am trying to print a global variable at a selective time using semaphores (NOTE- mutex, s1, s2, and memoryUsed all declared globally):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&s1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);

    pthread_t t0;
    pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &matrix_management, NULL);

    sem_wait(&s1); // wait for signal from pthread
    printf("Memory Usage from main: %d bytes\n\n", memoryUsed); // global var
    sem_post(&s2); // signal pthread to continue

    pthread_join(t0, NULL);
    sem_destroy(&s1);
    sem_destroy(&s2);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

In my target function, I want to stop at a selective point and print a global variable from main. Note, the variable is changed in the target function. Once I print, I want to continue the target function:

```
void *matrix_management(void *len)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // CHANGE GLOBAL VAR
    memoryUsed = 1;

    sem_post(&s1); // print from main
    sem_wait(&s2); // wait for signal

    // continue thread...


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}
```

However, the main thread does not seem to be waiting on the signal from the pthread at all. It immediately prints its the global variable's value. If I comment out the signal in the pthread, the program doesn't deadlock. Can you use semaphores between a MAIN thread and pthread like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your platform, unnamed semaphores may not be supported. The following would work in that case, though you may want to create temp names and use them later for the unlinks. The only reason I'm familiar with this is because the platform I normally work on, OS X, does not support unnamed semaphores through 10.8.3, and thus sans-error-checking I have similar behavior your seeing with your code because all the semaphore APIs fail.

Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <assert.h>

sem_t* s1=NULL, *s2=NULL;
int memoryUsed = 0;

void *matrix_management(void *len)
{
    // CHANGE GLOBAL VAR
    memoryUsed = 1;

    sem_post(s1); // print from main
    sem_wait(s2); // wait for signal
    printf("Thread woken up.\n");

    // continue thread...
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    s1 = sem_open("s1", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    s2 = sem_open("s2", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    assert(s1 && s2 && "Failed to allocate semaphores.");

    pthread_t t0;
    pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &matrix_management, NULL);

    sem_wait(s1); // wait for signal from pthread
    printf("Memory Usage from main: %d bytes.\n", memoryUsed); // global var

    printf("Waking thread...\n"); // global var
    sem_post(s2); // signal pthread to continue

    pthread_join(t0, NULL);
    printf("Thread finished\n");
    sem_close(s1);
    sem_close(s2);
    sem_unlink("s1");
    sem_unlink("s2");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Memory Usage from main: 1 bytes.
Waking thread...
Thread woken up.
Thread finished
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Did not know that about OS X. Thank you for your help!